# Fault in decimal to binary in c

Tags: c, ansi-c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    printf("Give a number in decimal form\n");
    int Division,a=1,sum=0,Bit,Digit;
    scanf("%d",&Division);
    do{
        Digit= Division%2;
        if (Digit==1){
            sum++;
        }
        Division/=2;
        Bit += Digit*a;
        a*=10;
    }while(Division>0);
    printf("%d is the number in binary form\n",Bit);
    printf("The number of 1s in the binary form is %d",sum);
}
```

The purpose of the exercise was to transform a decimal number to its binary form and count the 1s on it. It works just fine until 1023, but in 1024 it is printing "binary" numbers containing decimal digits. Note that the 1 count works correctly. Is the problem concerning the range?

Comment: Yes, you're probably overflowing `int Bit;`. Making it `long` might buy you some time, but you'd do better to assemble this into a string. I realise that's easier said than done in C in a neat way, but you could e.g. allocate a large buffer - say 33 characters (=32 bits + 1 for the nul) - and write into it backwards, checking you never overflow the 33.

Comment: If you **debug** your code and inspect the intermediate values of the variables then you should realize quickly that there is an integer overflow.

Comment: you need to initialize Bit to zero before you start.

Comment: You can also use logical and (`&`) to check the final bit, and right-shift to do the division by two. Or you can just scan each bit in turn with and rather than modifying `a` at all.

Comment: you can use a string to store zeros and ones and print that out rather than making a 10 based number that looks like a 2 based number

Comment: Range problem: Change `Bit` to type `unsigned long long` - good to 19 or 20 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get to the last (most significant) bit of 1024, the value of `a` is 10000000000 (10^10). Except it isn't. Because `int` is a 32-bit integer, the value of `a` overflows (twice) and ends up being 1410065408.